# Interview question: In php, is 123==0123?

Tags: php, comparison

I have answered it is false. then he asked why? i couldn't answer. Can anyone make the answer?  I am very interested to learn it.

Comment: I hate octal notation.

Comment: That's kind of a bullshit interview question.  That's one of those esoteric language quirks -- sure, people who are aware of it are obviously quite familiar with PHP, but that doesn't make them good programmers; similarly, if you don't know about it, that doesn't mean you're not a competent programmer.  We hired a guy with no PHP experience whatsoever into a PHP-writing position, 'cause he had at least a decade of experience in other languages.

Comment: Actually, it works like that in JavaScript too, and probably a few other languages.  So I wouldn't even be convinced that it told me whether they knew PHP.

Comment: It's not an esoteric language quirk, it's a notation common to many mainstream programming languages. Knowing about it says not much. **Not** knowing about it says much about detailed knowledge (or lack thereof). Kind of like whether `10 * 0.1` makes `1.0`...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Prefixing a number with `0` indicates octal (base 8), much the same way `0x` indicates hex (base 16).

Comment: Perhaps a bit of a nitpick, but I'd say "indicates" rather than "implies".  The `0` and `0x` prefixes *ex*plicitly indicate base, not *im*plicitly.

Answer (score 70):

This code:

```
var_dump(123);
var_dump(0123);
```

will get you:

```
int 123
int 83
```

This is because `0123` is octal notation *(because of the `0` at the beginning)*, while `123` is decimal.

For more information, you can take a look at the [Integer](http://php.net/integer) section of the manual.

An even trickier question would have been to ask about `79` and `079`, for instance :

```
var_dump(79);
var_dump(079);
```

will get you :

```
int 79
int 7
```

*(`9` is not a valid digit in octal ;-) )*

Answer (score 5):

1) When we use == operator in php, it checks if values are equal. 
 So 5=="5" => true
2) When we use === operator in php, it checks if values and data types are equal.
 So 5==="5" => false

123==0123 => false
ALSO 123 === 0123 => false

123 is decimal number : 123
0123 is an octal number (as it starts with 0) : 83

123 is not equal to 83

Answer (score 2):

Because 0123 means "123 in octal (base 8)", which is 83 in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

0123 is notation for an octal number (83 decimal, off the top of my head), whilst 123 is a decimal number. Therefore, they are not equal.