# I am not able to store 0123 in PHP Variable

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interview question: In php, is 123==0123?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412712/interview-question-in-php-is-123-0123)

I am newbie in PHP. I am trying to store 0123 in a PHP variable while learning PHP but it displays 83 instead of 0123 when I echo the variable. Can anyone give me exact technical reason of that.

Thanks in Advance,
Dhaval

Comment: Thanks for the link Marcel, I really didn't get this link else I not need to ask this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably doing something like this

```
$var = 0123;
```

This is an integer and not a string. Sidenote: "0123" is *not* a number, because no number has a leading `0` except `abs($var)<1` or `$var == 0`. But the leading `0` has a special meaning when used with integers: It is treated as a base-8-integer, which is then converted into base-10

```
               0123_8 = 83_10
1*8^2 + 2*8^1 + 3*8^0 = 8*10^1 + 3*10^0
```

Comment: Thanks KingCrunch for good explanation and answer

Answer (score 5):

Because you're probably trying to store is as an integer when you should be storing it as a string.

```
// Incorrect
$var = 0123 // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)

// Correct
$var = '0123'
```

Comment: Please add that `0123` is an octal value.

Comment: Hey John, Thanks for clear answer of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it like this:

```
$a = 0123;
```

Then you are using [octal numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) where indeed `0123 = 83`.